# How to get file data before upload in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I want to get file data **before** upload happens. I have tried this with the following command order

```
$this->upload->get_data()
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

but this gave empty results. (It works the other way round)

So my question is: how is possible to get file data in codeigniter **before** upload happens?

Comment: Then, use var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: @ReenaShirale Yes, I got it, thank you. Please edit your answer below and I'll mark it as a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump($_FILES); die; OR
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();
var_dump($upload_data); die;
```

Comment: Thanks, but $this->upload->data() returns data only after upload happens $this->upload->do_upload()

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not being uploading
you need to check this

```
$error = $this->upload->display_errors();
print_r($error);
```

and one thing more

```
$this->upload->do_upload('input_filed_name');
```